# Local Queue not appearing under the Queue folder

Tags: ibm-mq, message-queue

I have created a local queue, using MQ Explorer, but I cannot see it in MQ Explorer's list of queues. Here is a screen shot of what I see in MQ Explorer:

[image]

I expect the Local Queue to appear under the Queue folder.

If I right-click on the Queue folder and select Status, I can see it, as shown in this second screen shot. So I know that the queue has definitely been created.

[image]

Comment: You first image does not show that the queue was not created?  How did you create the queue?  Was it in mq explorer or some other method?

Comment: Did you refresh the view of the queue folder after you created the queue? If you created the queue outside of Explorer, you either have to manually refresh or wait for the next automatic refresh to show the newly created queue.

Comment: yes it does not show my created Queue. I created it through MQ Websphere Explorer. Already refreshed it as well. but it does not appear

Comment: Could you please provide a screen shot that actually shows the list of queues that are in the queue folder rather than just a picture of the queue folder - which doesn't show that the queue isn't there.

Comment: @MoragHughson question reopened if you still want to answer with screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing IBM MQ objects, such as queues, with MQ Explorer, the display is split into two panes, "MQ Explorer - Navigator" and "MQ Explorer - Content".

[image: MQ Explorer showing Navigator and Content pane headings]

Clicking on a "folder" in the Navigator pane causes items to be shown in the Content pane.

[image: Queue folder selected - Queues shown in Content pane]

If you don't see the list of queues when you click on the "Queues" folder in the Navigator pane, this could be because you have closed the Content pane. To re-open the Content pane, use the Window menu, and choose "Show View" and then choose "MQ Explorer - Content". This will re-instate your Content pane, and you can then select the "Queues" folder and see the list of queues in the Content pane.

[image]